# Google Charts: Hiding vertical bars on points

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Line Chart</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">      
            google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
            google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

            function drawChart() {
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([  
                ['Year', 'Sales', {role: 'annotation'}, 'Expenses', {role: 'annotation'}],
                ['2014',  1000, '',      400, ''],
                ['2015',  1170, '',      460, ''],
                ['2016',  660, '',       1120, ''],
                ['2017',  1030, '$1030', 540, '$540']
            ]);

            var options = {
                title: 'Company Performance',
                curveType: 'function',
                legend: { position: 'bottom' },
                pointSize:0,
                annotations: {
                alwaysOutside: false,
                textStyle: {
                    fontSize: 12,
                    color: '#000',
                    auraColor: 'none'
                }
                }
            };

            var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

            chart.draw(data, options);
}

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Which displays the following chart

[image]

Do you see those vertical gray lines on points? How can I hide them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the missing annotation values, use `null` instead of a blank string `''`

```
['2014', 1000, null, 400, null],
```

we can also control the color of the vertical line pointing to the annotation,
otherwise known as the `stem`...

```
              stem: {
                color: 'transparent'
              },
```

add above option within the `annotations` option...

```
                annotations: {
                  alwaysOutside: false,
                  stem: {
                    color: 'transparent'
                  },
                  textStyle: {
                    fontSize: 12,
                    color: '#000',
                    auraColor: 'none'
                  }
                }
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
            google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

            function drawChart() {
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([  
                ['Year', 'Sales', {role: 'annotation'}, 'Expenses', {role: 'annotation'}],
                ['2014',  1000, null,      400, null],
                ['2015',  1170, null,      460, null],
                ['2016',  660, null,       1120, null],
                ['2017',  1030, '$1030', 540, '$540']
            ]);

            var options = {
                title: 'Company Performance',
                curveType: 'function',
                legend: { position: 'bottom' },
                pointSize:0,
                annotations: {
                  alwaysOutside: false,
                  stem: {
                    color: 'transparent'
                  },
                  textStyle: {
                    fontSize: 12,
                    color: '#000',
                    auraColor: 'none'
                  }
                }
            };

            var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

            chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

Comment: Can I hide that gray vertical bar?

Comment: got it, sure, see edit above...

Comment: Brilliant! It seels Google Charts are more accessible and more flexible than Charts.js. Can I run chart library standalone my server instead of using Google?

Comment: check the [FAQ](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/faq), there are questions for "Can I use charts offline?" and "Can I download and host the chart code locally, or on an intranet?"